# How to return an array of string with a particular word?

Tags: arrays, string, filter

I want to return an array of string with a particular word. For example, if I want all the strings with the Squirrel word, how to do ?

**Input**

*[ 'Blue Squirrel', 'Pink Horse', 'Yellow Squirrel', 'Green Cat', 'White Frog', 'Black Lion', 'Orange Squirrel' ]*

**Return**

*[ 'Blue Squirrel', 'Yellow Squirrel', 'Orange Squirrel' ]*

My code :

```
function iJustWantSquirrel (animals) {
  const onlySquirrels = animals.filter(function(animal) {
    if (animal.length == 'Squirrel') {
      return animal;
    } 
  });
  return onlySquirrels;
}
```

Comment: this looks like a homework assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find whether a string includes a word which you can do by using `includes` method. Also when you use filter, the callback only needs to return a boolean value and not the actual value to be returned

```js
const data = [ 'Blue Squirrel', 'Pink Horse', 'Yellow Squirrel', 'Green Cat', 'White Frog', 'Black Lion', 'Orange Squirrel' ]
function iJustWantSquirrel (animals) {
  const onlySquirrels = animals.filter(function(animal) {
    return animal.toLowerCase().includes('squirrel')
  });
  return onlySquirrels;
}

console.log(iJustWantSquirrel(data));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter out the elements you don't want, like this:

```
const array = [ 
    'Blue Squirrel', 
    'Pink Horse', 
    'Yellow Squirrel', 
    'Green Cat', 
    'White Frog', 
    'Black Lion', 
    'Orange Squirrel' 
];

const result = array.filter(s => s.toLowerCase().indexOf('squirrel') >= 0);
```

This returns:

```
["Blue Squirrel", "Yellow Squirrel", "Orange Squirrel"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just changed a little bit your snippet to check wether or not the word 'Squirrel' exists in the string.

```js
function iJustWantSquirrel (animals) {
  const onlySquirrels = animals.filter((animal) => {
    if (animal.includes('Squirrel')) {
      return animal;
    } 
  });
  return onlySquirrels;
}

const animalArray = [ 'Blue Squirrel', 'Pink Horse', 'Yellow Squirrel', 'Green Cat', 'White Frog', 'Black Lion', 'Orange Squirrel' ];

const newAnimalArray = iJustWantSquirrel(animalArray);

alert(JSON.stringify(newAnimalArray));
```